# Having trouble sending form field with same names using Javascript to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with with a simple input field and I have a button that will allow me to add another input field via javascript using the same name(eg: name="list[]"). When I click the 'add' button to enter multiple email addresses it dynamically adds the new input field but the problem I'm having is when I send it to the PHP script the script only returns the first e-mail and not the others. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

-javascript below-

```
function preparePage() {
  var addEmail = document.getElementById("add_email");
  var putEmail = document.getElementById("put_email");

  addEmail.onclick = function() {
    putEmail.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="names_list[]"><br />';
    };
 }

window.onload =  function() {
  preparePage();
};
```

-html below-

```
  <form action="email_names.php" method="post">
    <div id="put_email">
      <input type="text" name="names_list[]"><br />
    </div>

    <div>
      <div id="add_email"> + </div>

      <input id="email_btn" type="submit" name="email_submit" value="E-mail List">
    </div>
  </form>
```

-php script below-

```
  if(isset($_POST['email_submit'])) {
    $names_list = $_POST['names_list'];

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($names_list);
    echo '<pre>';
}

//This returns 
Array
(
  [0] => test@email1.com
)
// instead of
Array
(
  [0] => test@email1.com
  [1] => test@email2.com
  [2] => test@email3.com
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Typos?</strike>

```
putEmail.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="name_list[]"   snip....
                                                ^^^^-- singular name: no "s"



  <input type="text" name="names_list[]"><br />
                           ^^^^^---plural names. WITH "s"
```

Doing a `var_dump($_POST)` would confirm this.

---

and now I see the OP's done a ninja-edit and fixed this up, so guess not...

Comment: You were correct, I did have a typo and now I fixed it in both the OP and my script, but I am still only getting one email returned when I use print_r().

Comment: Ok, my dumbass forgot to the refresh the page after I fixed the typo, Thank you Marc.